# WIN11 VM Does Not Start

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, lxc, lxd

I recently installed win11 vm using the method shown here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd#1-overview.

I finished the installation up to end of step 3 where windows setup should start automatically.  It does not.

I am not proficient with Linux/Ubuntu and would appreciate some help.  I dont know how to trigger the windows installation to start so that i can continue setup.  when i reboot, there is not option to start win11 in vm mode.

thanks

Comment: As this is a question related to the installation of Windows (in a virtual environment), you better raise the question in a forum focusing on Windowssupport.